# Is it possible to replicate the effect of vim's `zz` in bash?

Tags: bash, vim

In Vim, executing `zz` in normal mode will take the line the cursor is currently on, and move that line, together with the cursor, to the vertical center of the current window.

Is there a way to replicate this behavior in `bash`, to move the current command prompt to the vertical center of the screen, and scroll the command buffer along with it?

I am posting on StackOverflow instead of `Unix/Linux` because I am open to solutions that require writing custom code if bash does not natively support this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the shell, it would be a feature of the terminal emulator.

Comment: Vim is a program that can run directly in the shell, and it has knowledge of where its "vertical center" is, even through an `ssh` session or inside another tool like `tmux`. Why is it not possible for `bash` to do the same?

Comment: @Barmar are you suggesting this has nothing to do with `vim` too?

Comment: `vim` is a full-screen application that takes control of the terminal. `bash` operates a line at a time on the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

n.m. has already explained that bash itself cannot do it.  However, you still might be able to send commands directly to the underlying terminal to achieve an effect similar to what you want.  For example, assuming that your bash input line is somewhere below the middle of the screen, the following will scroll down by sending a couple of empty lines and then putting you into the middle of the screen:

```
 declare -i L; declare -i M; L=`tput lines`/2; M=$L-1; for (( c=1; c<=$L; c++ )); do echo; done; tput cup $M
```

Note that this doesn't work when your somewhere in the upper half of the screen (it will put you into the middle of the screen, but will not scroll back).

For more info see `man tput` and `man terminfo`.

Comment: I have tested this solution locally, through `ssh`, and inside a `tmux` session, and it achieves the desired effect.

Answer (score 4):

Vim controls the entire area of the screen. Bash is only responsible for the input line. It has no idea about the contents of the rest of the screen, which is/was under control of other programs, and cannot reposition it.

Note that the contents of the screen nornally cannot be read by a program running on it. The only way to know what's on the screen is to start from a clean state and account for every single character and terminal command printed. Vim does just that; Bash does not and can not.